# Js, function not working

Tags: javascript

```
`var y = 0 ;
var x = 0;
function atm(num1, num2){
console.log((num1 - num2));
return num1 - num2 ;
}
var items =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function vm(y, x){
if( atm(y , items[x]) < 0  ){
    result = "U Do not have enough money to pay";
}
else if ( atm(y , items[x]) === 0  );{
    result = "Ur money just matches the required paying fee";
}
if ( atm(y , items[x]) > 0  );{
    result="U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder";
}
}

vm(2, 3);`
```

**the error is that  it gives me 3 answers as u can see:
\\
-2

"U Do not have enough money to pay"

"Ur money just matches the required paying fee"

-2

"U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder"
\\

\\ 
also the 3rd result "  result="U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder" " wont show the remainder

"y goes to the amount of money u hold"

"x goes to the number of items from array"

vm is the vending machine and what it should do is show 1 answer of these up

1- u do not have enough money to pay

2- Ur money just matches the required paying fee

3- is that he has more money and he will reserve " y - items[x] " as remainder

**Please when u got my error write me the error and the full code, sometimes it gets hard on me, im still new...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is right.

```
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function atm(num1, num2){
  return num1 - num2;
}


function vm(y, x) {
  if( atm(y, items[x]) < 0  ) {
      result = "You Do not have enough money to pay";
  }
  else if ( atm(y, items[x]) === 0  ) {
      result = "Ur money just matches the required paying fee";
  }
  else {
      result = "U will reserve " + atm(y, items[x]) +" as a remainder";
  }
  return result;
}

vm(2, 3)
// "You Do not have enough money to pay"
```

Comment: Thank u alot u saved me my friend <3